# How to limit the resizing area when using jquery ui

Tags: html, jquery, css

I am resizing a div area using jquery ui.

I want to limit the resizing to a specific area.

containment:"parent"

When you add the code, the drag becomes the area limit.
However, the size adjustment is not limited to the area.

[image]

I want to resize only in the blue area, but it fails.

What are you doing wrong?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            #main_container{
                position : absolute;
                top:50%;
                left:50%;
                width: 800px;
                height: 500px;
                margin-left:-400px;
                margin-top:-250px;
                border : solid 1px black;
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: column;
            }
            
            #control_container{
                border : solid 1px black;
            }
            
            #object_container{
                background-color : blue;
                flex: 1;
                border : solid 1px black;               
            }
            
            #control_container > p, button {
                float:left;
                margin:0 5px 0 0;
            }
            
            #test, #test2
            {
                width : 100px;
                height : 100px;
                border : solid 1px black;
                position : absolute;
                background-color : red;
            }
        </style>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        
        <div id="main_container">
            <div id="control_container">
                <button>test</button>
                <button>test</button>
                <button>test</button>
                <p>test</p>
                <button>test</button>
                <p>test</p>
                <button>test</button>
            </div>
            <div id="object_container">
                <div id="test"></div>
                <div id="test2"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script>
            $('#test').draggable({  
                containment:"parent",
            });
        
            $('#test').resizable({ 
                containment:"parent",
                handles: 'n, e, s, w, ne, se, sw, nw',  
            });
            
            $('#test2').draggable({ 
                containment:"parent",
            });
        
            $('#test2').resizable({ 
                containment:"parent",
                handles: 'n, e, s, w, ne, se, sw, nw',  
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I need to resize two or more div objects,

The position should be absolute.

Dragging is limited to the area, but resizing is not limited to the area?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this code, To How to limit the resizing area when using jquery ui.

```js
$(function () {
    var containerWidth = $("#body").width();
    var getCurrentBlockRight = function ($currentBlock) {
        var $parent = $currentBlock.parent();
        return $currentBlock.offset().left + $currentBlock.outerWidth() - $parent.offset().left - parseInt($parent.css("padding-left"), 10);
    };
    $('.block').resizable({
        maxWidth: containerWidth,
        minHeight: 32,
        minWidth: 15,
        start: function (event, ui) {
            var $currentBlock = $(this);
            var width = $(this).width();
            $currentBlock.resizable("option", "maxWidth", width + containerWidth - getCurrentBlockRight($currentBlock));
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.block
{
    border: 1px dashed gray;
    display: inline-block;
    min-height: 32px;
    width: 130px;
}

#body
{
    width: 500px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    min-height: 50px;
    padding: 10px;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="body">
    <div class="block">test1</div>
    <div class="block">test2</div>
    <div class="block">test3</div>
    <div class="block">test4</div>
    <div class="block">test5</div>
    <div class="block">test6</div>
    <div class="block">test7</div>
</div>
```

I hope this code will be useful to you.

Thank you.